# Models in a Simple PyMongo-based Blogging Web App without ORM/ODM

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am currently using PyMongo + Flask for building a simple blogging application. I am not using any kind of ODM, instead I decided to use PyMongo directly. I need to know how to improve my code since learning is my main motivation for building this application.

This portion of code is implemented in a view controller called `post.py` and it is used to edit a post:

```py
@posts.route('/<_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(_id):
    post = Post()
    post.get(_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.title = request.form.get('title')
        post.tags = [tag.strip() for tag in 
                     request.form.get('tags').split(',')]
        post.body = request.form.get('body')
        post.update()
    return render_template('posts_edit.html', post=post)
```

The Post model looks something like this:

```py
class Post:
    def __init__(self, _id=None, title=None, status=None, tags=None, 
                 body=None, date=None, author=None):
        self._id = _id
        self.title = title
        self.status = status
        self.tags = tags
        self.body = body
        self.date = date
        self.author = author

    def save(self):
        mongo.db.posts.insert_one({
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "title": self.title,
            "status": self.status,
            "tags": self.tags,
            "body": self.body,
            "date": datetime.utcnow(),
            "author": self.author
        })

    def update(self):
        mongo.db.posts.update({
            '_id': self._id
        },
            {
                "title": self.title,
                "status": self.status,
                "tags": self.tags,
                "body": self.body,
                "date": self.date,
                "author": self.author
        })

    def get(self, _id):
        post = mongo.db.posts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)})
        if post:
            self.__init__(**post)
            return self
        return None

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        return mongo.db.posts.find()
```

Is this the right direction?

Comment: _"Is this the right direction?"_ Does it work properly?

Comment: Yes, but is this bad code? I am worried about the quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the route I'd probably use fewer temporary variables, not that it
hurts a lot, but it can be more compact.  Additionally if `Post`
implemented some sort of `dict`-like `update` function it could be even
more compact, but that's splitting hairs.

```
@posts.route('/<_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(_id):
    post = Post()
    post.get(_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.title = request.form.get('title')
        post.tags = [tag.strip()
                     for tag in request.form.get('tags').split(',')]
        post.body = request.form.get('body')
        post.update()
    return render_template('posts_edit.html', post=post)
```

With the latter point I mean something like this (implemention left as
an exercise for the reader):

```
@posts.route('/<_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(_id):
    post = Post()
    post.get(_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.update({
            "title": request.form.get('title'),
            "tags": [tag.strip()
                    for tag in request.form.get('tags').split(',')]
            "body": request.form.get('body')
        })
    return render_template('posts_edit.html', post=post)
```

For the other file I'd suggest looking at the usual 80 character limit,
meaning wrapping the longer lines a bit.

- In `save` the `date` and `_id` attributes of the object aren't being
  used - that looks inconsistent, either `self.date` and `self._id`
  should be updated too, or neither, right?  That should probably also
  be documented clearly.
- With `get` and the `__init__` call, AFAIK that's probably safe, but
  coming from any background where constructors are, well, that, this
  looks fishy.  Consider making that a class method too:

  ```
  @classmethod
  def get(cls, _id):
      return cls(**mongo.db.posts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)}))
  ```
- `get_all` doesn't use it's argument, so it's actually more of a
  `staticmethod` right now.  If you're no going to use inheritance make
  it one then.  If you are, possibly make move `mongo.db.posts` into a
  class variable so that you could override it for subclasses and the
  methods would keep on working with the correct tables.

Comment: `self._id` and `self.date` should not be updated, but you are right about documenting it. Your second point is absolutely valid. Lastly, I am indeed planning on using inheritance. Thanks a lot!